# How to omit middle parameters in a function that has default parameters?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

int sumofthree(int a=1, int b=2, int c=3) {
  return a+b+c;
}

int main ()
{
  std::cout << sumofthree(5); //10
  std::cout << sumofthree(5,3); //11
  std::cout << sumofthree(1,,2); //error

  return 0;
}
```

Is it possible to omit passing middle parameters? If so, how to?
(Without using `#macros`)

Comment: Nope. Can't do it.

Comment: No, it's not possible.

Comment: Allright, close this or should I delete this?

Comment: It's a valid question and no one has brought forth a dupe. Please keep it. Just because the answer is "no" does not mean that the question is any less interesting.

Comment: Keep in mind that a good question is one that others are asking too. This one definitely fits the bill.

Comment: And there's the dupe.

Answer (score 4):

What you are asking for is not possible.